# Roslyn How to Compare Tokens

Tags: c#, code-analysis, roslyn

I wrote a function to check if a variable has been assigned to but I can't figure out how I should compare the nodes:

```
    private static bool IsAssignment(SyntaxNode node)
    {
        if (node is ArgumentSyntax)
        {
            //This doesn't work even though both are ref tokens
            return node.ChildTokens().Any(t => t == SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.RefKeyword));
        }

        return node is AssignmentExpressionSyntax;
    }
```

I was thinking of using the ValueText Property but that just seemed wrong

When I Compare the Child token to the one create by the syntax factory they don't match How can I compare tokens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Token comparisons [include the parent](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Syntax/SyntaxToken.cs,549).

Instead, you should check whether its `RawKind` is `SyntaxKind.RefKeyword`.

Comment: Just to make sure, raw kind is an int, it is the castes enum

Answer (score 1):

I needed the same thing and I believe that currently the recommended way is to use `IsKind` like this:

```
bool isRef = node.ChildTokens().Any(t => t.IsKind(SyntaxKind.RefKeyword));
```